# Not being able to use css file and bootstrap theme together in the project

Tags: plotly-dash

The changes I make in the s1.css file are not showing up in the webpage . can u please tell what to use :
[Here is my code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnBK3.png)

I tried adding an extra file 's1.css' so i can make extra changes to the css apart from bootstrap. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store the CSS file? It should be in: project_folder/assets/

Also, try to use some other theme or just general "BOOTSRAP" in your "dbc.themes." part of code.

I would need to see the whole code to be able to help you more.

Comment: When I saved the my css file in the other 'assets' folder , it worked. Thanks for the help and is there a particular reason why you suggested to use BOOTSTRAP compared to other themes, you see i am very new to this so just wanted to know.

Comment: A reason behind the suggestion was to find out whether the themes do not work in general due to a mistake in your script or whether a mistake occurs in Dash due to possible clashes of specific theme version with something else (I am also new in this, have been using Dash for a month or so)